# git checkout branches for development/staging/production

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout, git-worktree

I am currently restructuring how our company is handling development procedures. Since it is quite the hazzle for us to always ssh into the server to promote files/folders from DEV to STAGE/PRODUCTION servers I thought it might be a good idea to setup the git environment in a way that would allow us to simple merge the dev-branch into the stage-branch to perform a "promotion".

For this we would need 3 different branches in our projects which checkout to different locations on the server when a new push is received.

Lets say we have 3 folders on our server which contain the data for our 3 different environments (DEV - STAGE - PROD). Then the schema would look somewhat like this:

[Branch checkout schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShlS6.png)

I set up the git as bare repos and I was wondering if something of that sort is possible with git.

I will be grateful for every bit of help you guys can provide me with! :D

Comment: This is a very standard setup.  What is your question?

Comment: Well, I did not know of that solution yet that's why I was asking. Carlo did provide me with a great solution to this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the idea is to use a `post-receive hook` on the server and setting a forced 
 (`-f` option) checkout in a specific directory

you can obtain a checkout in a specific working directory using the `--work-tree=/path/` option...

a sample code (to be saved on the bare repos on the server as file `hooks/post-receive` with execution bit set) adapted by [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/bad-mushroom/9844887) could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---'
echo 'Deploying site...'
echo '--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---'

if ! [ -t 0 ]; then
    read -a ref
fi

IFS='/' read -ra REF <<< "${ref[2]}"
branch="${REF[2]}"

# Master Branch
if [ "PROD" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/path/to/public/PROD checkout -f $branch
    echo 'Changes pushed to production site'
fi

# Stage Branch
if [ "STAGE" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/path/to/public/STAGE checkout -f $branch
    echo 'Changes pushed to stage site'
fi

# Development Branch
if [ "DEV" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=/path/to/public/DEV checkout -f $branch
    echo 'Changes pushed to dev site'
fi

echo '--- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- --- ---'
```

another possible sintax for the checkout is

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/path/to/test/site git checkout -f
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me out on this. 
I was a bit blind in adding my post-receive hook ;) ... It did not come to my mind that you yould use a full fletched Shellscript here, since I was never using anything other than the standard work-tree settings.

Comment: perfect... happy to be useful